# Arduino circuit for high-power LED and servos

Tags: arduino, led, servo

I am hoping to hook up two servos and a high power (1 W) LED to an Arduino to control them. Due to my inexperience, I thought it would be best to check here to see if this circuit will work.

My main uncertainties about this circuit are:

- Is the LM317 transistor the right component?
- Is the 100 Ω Resistor the right size for the 1 W (3.3 V, 0.33 A) LED?

If someone is able to give some advice for this set up that would be amazing. I apologise in advance for the non-standard diagram (image attached).

[image: Circuit Diagram for Arduino with 2 servos and 1 high power LED]

Circuit Lab (UPDATED) circuit below:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fGLSSN.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: You have no pin numbers or functions on the LM317, etc., so it's difficult to know. It appears that you are trying to power the LM317 from D3 which will have a 20 to 40 mA max current so that won't work. The LM317 is a voltage regulator (not a "transistor). There are many transistors inside it. There's a CircuitLab schematic button on the editor toolbar. It's easy to use and saves an editable schematic in-line in your question. There's a custom component which you can modify for any odd-bod bits. Double-click to set parameters, pins, etc. 'R', 'H' and 'V' for rotate, horiz-flip and vert-flip.

Comment: For the LED, the 100 ohm resistor powered by 5 volts limits the 3.3-volt LED to less than about one twentieth of a Watt, which is probably not what you want. Oh, yes... and don't forget to heat sink the LED when you do get closer to 1 Watt.

Comment: It's normally best to use a current controller or LDO regulator to drive high power leds rather than a resistor.  You can either use the arduino to perform current regulation or find a current controller for your LED that has a logic level input.

Comment: Thank you all for your help in this matter! It seems I may have been way off the mark in terms of the LED circuitry. I have updated the post with a CircuitLab circuit, with some minor changes. Please do advise if there are any more errors!

@Transistor thanks for your help. Regards the Voltage Regulator LM317 (thanks for the clarification) I wasn't trying to power from D3, it should have been powering from the (5V step down), taking control from D3, and outputting to the LED.

Comment: @MicroservicesOnDDD cheers for letting me know! What size resistor would limit the voltage appropriately?

Comment: The LM317 is a voltage vregulator - it tries to keep its output voltage about 1.25 volts above the voltage at the output pin.  It can be used as a current regulator - see the LM317 datasheet for a sample circuit - however, it won't work in this case, as there is insufficient "headroom" fro the regulator to operate.  You need a 5.1 Ohm 1 Watt resistor as R1, to limit the LED current to 0.33 Amp.  Use a transistor or MOSFET to turn the LED off and on.

Comment: @Base: I took the liberty of tidying up your schematic a bit. Using the GND symbol eliminates several "wires", improves the legibility and gives instant visualisation of the voltage at those nodes. I also aligned some of the components to eliminated corners on the wiring.

Comment: Rather than complex power source conversions to low V high power LED, consider LEDs that match your power source of 12V such as 1W worth of LEDstrips or 4x  <3V LEDs + small R. @ 80 ~ 100mA

Comment: Thank you very much for tidying up the circuit diagram @Transistor! It is much appreciated. I just have one query regards the circuit layout if that's alright. I've been receiving different information from different people! Which method would be better to use? 

A) Use the LM317 and a 1000Ω resistor
B) Use a transistor and a 5.1Ω resistor

Thank you very much to everyone else also for your help in this!

Comment: The LM317 can be configured as voltage regulator or current regulator. You don't need a voltage regulator as you already have two in your circuit and as been pointed out it needs some "headroom" which means that to get 3.3 V out may require > 6 V in. To get that in your circuit means drawing power from the 12 V supply and dropping 8.7 V at 330 mA = almost 3 W in the linear regulator or resistor combined. A switching regulator fed from the 12 V source and set to 330 mA would be the best solution. See if CrossRoads' solution makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a constant current driver for the LED such as this

https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/infineon-technologies/BCR420UE6327HTSA1/BCR420UE6327HTSA1CT-ND/2270374

See page 23
https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-BCR420U-BCR421U-DS-v02_01-EN.pdf?fileId=5546d4626102d35a01617524f09e061d

The driver prevents the current from increasing as the LED heats up and tries to allow even more current to flow, leading to an overheating/burnout condition.

Comment: This chip's maximum current is 150 mA, less than half of what a 1 watt LED likely requires.

Comment: 5V x 200mA = 1W, yes?  150 x 5V = 750mW. How are you getting < 0,5W?

Comment: The question is by quite explicit statement about supplying **330 mA** across an LED drop of approximately 3.3v.  You can't calculate LED power from the supply voltage to the driver, but only from the drop actually across the LED *excluding* that across the current regulator.   And the chip is designed for only 150 mA.

Comment: You are right, I missed that. I saw the 12V to 5V converter going into the LED and was thinking 5V. There are other similar current controllers for 3.3V and higher current. Power them with 12V and let the controller output the correct current for the resulting Vf of the LED.

Comment: With the kind of headroom of 12v in hopefully a switching regulator, or more dies in series, otherwise 1 watt into the LED means nearly 3 up in heat in a linear regulator.

Comment: A DC-DC switching regulator controller such as this one will supply up to 500mA from a 12V supply with just a couple components needed - current sense resistor, schottky diode, inductor, and 2 caps.  Datasheet includes a link for an online tool for selecting components  https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/maxim-integrated/MAX16822BASA/MAX16822BASA-ND/1937624     https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX16822-MAX16822B.pdf

Comment: Well, I can't get link to the tool to work, it opens to something else. A check with Maxim engineering will be needed for component selection.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help @CrossRoads. I will look into the CC LED Driver as an option for this circuit!